# Regex for divide sentence into words with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need divide sentece into words with special characters separately in JAVASCRIPT.

```
INPUT: "This is: dragée/ (my) test? one sentence."

OUTPUT: ['This', 'is', ':', 'dragée', '/', '(', 'my', ')', 'test', '?', 'one', 'sentence', '.']
```

my attempt:

```
sentence.split(/\b(?!\s)/)
```

OUTPUT: ['This', 'is', ':', 'drag', 'é', 'e', '/(', 'my', ')', 'text', '?', 'one', 'sentence']

Diacritics are also important. Thanks for help.

Comment: please make/show your attempt before asking. does it have to be regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```js
const text = "This is: dragée/ (my) test? one sentence."

const result = text.split(/([ :\/\(\)?.])/g).filter(e => e.trim())

console.log(result)
```